# B-spline Curve in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Could anyone help me about B-spline Curve error?

I want to draw B-spline Curve in c++, but even though all coordinates are positive, the segment's coordinate is negative.

This is B-spline Curve code.

```
void BSplineCurve(Dot &ControlPoint1, Dot &ControlPoint2, 
                  Dot &ControlPoint3,Dot &ControlPoint4, 
                  Dot &DrawCurve, double &t){

    double t2 = t * t;
    double t3 = t2 * t;
    double mt3 = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t);

    double bi3 = mt3 / 6;
    double bi2 = ((3 * t3) - (6 * t2) + 4) / 6;
    double bi1 = ((-3 * t3) + (3 * t2) + (3 * t) + 1) / 6;
    double bi  = mt3 / 6;

    DrawCurve.x = ControlPoint1.x * bi3;
    DrawCurve.x += ControlPoint2.x * bi2;
    DrawCurve.x += ControlPoint3.x * bi1;
    DrawCurve.x += ControlPoint4.x * bi;

    DrawCurve.y = ControlPoint1.y * bi3;
    DrawCurve.y += ControlPoint2.y * bi2;
    DrawCurve.y += ControlPoint3.y * bi1;
    DrawCurve.y += ControlPoint4.y * bi;
}
```

This is Drawing Code.

```
double t = 3.f;
do{

    if ((3 < t) && (t <= 4)) {
    BSplineCurve(ControlPoint1, ControlPoint2, ControlPoint3, ControlPoint4, DrawCurve, t);
    Draw1Dot(DrawCurve.x, DrawCurve.y, DrawCurve.R, DrawCurve.G, DrawCurve.B);
    }
    else if ((4 < t) && (t <= 5)) {
    BSplineCurve(ControlPoint2, ControlPoint3, ControlPoint4, ControlPoint5, DrawCurve, t);
    Draw1Dot(DrawCurve.x, DrawCurve.y, DrawCurve.R, DrawCurve.G, DrawCurve.B);
    }
    else if ((5 < t) && (t <= 6)) {
    BSplineCurve(ControlPoint3, ControlPoint4, ControlPoint5, ControlPoint6, DrawCurve, t);
    Draw1Dot(DrawCurve.x, DrawCurve.y, DrawCurve.R, DrawCurve.G, DrawCurve.B);
    }
    t += 0.001;
} while(t < 6.001);
```

This is Control Point's coordinate.

Poiont1 : 50, 50

Poiont2 : 50, 100

Poiont3 : 200, 100

Poiont4 : 200, 50

Poiont5 : 350, 50

Poiont6 : 350, 100

But this is 1st segment's coordinate.

Q3 : -1543, -349

Comment: Don't know the formula, you try to implement, but bi, bi1 and bi3 are all negative, so the result is no suprise

Comment: https://github.com/ejmahler/SplineLibrary This might interest you. This is an open source library I made a few years ago with a b-spline implementation in it, hopefully it will help you figure out what to do next

Comment: @MikeMB
I agree with your opinion.
I was confused about the concept of parameters but finished today.
The curves were also drawn neatly and the formula was revised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawing code looks wrong.

In function `BSplineCurve` the `t` parameter should take values in [0, 1] range. By changing `t` from 0 to 1 one will build a cubic B-spline between points `ControlPoint2` and `ControlPoint3`.

You could try something like:

```
Dot points[6] = {ControlPoint1, ControlPoint2, ControlPoint3, ControlPoint4, ControlPoint5, ControlPoint6};
for(double t = 3.0; t < 6.0; t += 0.001)
{
    const int start = static_cast<int>(t);
    BSplineCurve(points[start - 3], 
                 points[start - 2], 
                 points[start - 1], 
                 points[start], 
                 DrawCurve, 
                 t - start);
    Draw1Dot(DrawCurve.x, DrawCurve.y, DrawCurve.R, DrawCurve.G, DrawCurve.B);
}
```

---

#### Update

Your B-spline calculation code looks wrong too :-)

`bi` should be `t3/6.0` and not `mt3/6.0`. See [here](http://caig.cs.nctu.edu.tw/course/NM07S/slides/chap3_3.pdf) (slide 25).

---

The fixed function can look something like this (I did not test it):

```
void BSplineCurve(const Dot &point1, 
                  const Dot &point2, 
                  const Dot &point3,
                  const Dot &point4, 
                  const double t,
                  Dot &result)
{
    const double t2 = t * t;
    const double t3 = t2 * t;
    const double mt = 1.0 - t;
    const double mt3 = mt * mt * mt;

    const double bi3 = mt3;
    const double bi2 = 3 * t3 - 6 * t2 + 4;
    const double bi1 =-3 * t3 + 3 * t2 + 3 * t + 1;
    const double bi  = t3;

    result.x = point1.x * bi3 + 
               point2.x * bi2 +
               point3.x * bi1 +
               point4.x * bi;
    result.x /= 6.0;

    result.y = point1.y * bi3 + 
               point2.y * bi2 +
               point3.y * bi1 +
               point4.y * bi;
    result.y /= 6.0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful! Thank you :)

The curves seem strange, but the dots are visible.

I need to modify drawing alghrithm...

Comment: I think I've found your error, fixed the answer @Kim BeomSik

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the point you use is too very close. In spline it is not good iidea to use very close point. becaue so we have very "galloping" curve. Like this:

[image]

red is original

Comment: Thank to your answer.
But I am studying B-spline curve now.
If I want to draw a curve, I will take your answer. :)